# fscanf with colon (:) delimited data

Tags: c, file, field, scanf

How do I `fscanf` this piece of data? There are no empty rows between the data and delimeter is a `':'`

```
VS1234567890654327:Rob Fordfirst:001:200
VS1234567890654312:Steven Harper:200:010
```

**my code**

```
while(3==fscanf(filename, "????", &string[size], &name[size], &number1[size], &number2[size])) {
    //printf("%s - %s - %.3d - %.3d", string[size], name[size], number1[size], number2[size]));
    size++;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can include the delimiters as part of your format to `fscanf`, like this:

```
while (4 == fscanf(filename, "%[^:]:%[^:]:%d:%d", string[size], name[size], &number1[size], &number2[size])) {
    ...
}
```

Note the use of `%[^:]` format specifier. It says "any character except `':'` is accepted". Also note that `char*` parameters are passed with no ampersand, because they are already pointers.

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/kVBLYX)

Comment: Thanks! That helped. What about for data files like this?
`039 Mt Albert Rd, Holland landing (lots of spaces) 9.50
043 Queensville Side Road, Queensville (lots of spaces) 10.00`