# Using fscanf on text file with fixed-width columns

Tags: c, file, scanf

How do I use `fscanf()` to parse this piece of data? There are lots of spaces between the string and the double.

```
039 Mt Albert Rd, Holland landing                9.50
043 Queensville Side Road, Queensville           10.00

while(3==fscanf(filename, "%d?????%lf\n", &int[size], &string[size], &double[size])) {
    size++;
}
```

Comment: Are there a fixed number of commas in the address field?

Comment: See [C Programming - fscanf and delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450333/fscanf-with-colon-delimited-data) for Part 1.

Comment: The string contains up to 34 characters and the integers and doubles are aligned

Answer (score 2):

If the start of the double is always in the same column (50 in your example), scanf the string from there:

```
char buf[120];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
    if (isdigit(buf[0])
    &&  sscanf(buf, "%d", &int[size])==1
    &&  sscanf(buf+50, "%f", &double[size])==1)
        size++;
}
```

or if you really are interested in the string as well

```
while (sscanf(fp, "%3d%47c%f", &int[size], &string[size], &double[size])==3) {
    // remove trailing blanks from the string
    int pos=strlen(string[size])-1;
    while (pos>=0 && string[size][pos]==' ')
        pos--;
    string[size][++pos]='\0';
}
```

Comment: You should probably put a space before the `%47c` to skip the spaces between the end of the number and the start of the string. You should also note that you can't really have an array called `int` or an array called `double`.

Comment: Agree. I assumed the thread starter was aware of that, and wanted to stay as close to his example as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need three values, the integer, a string and a double, and the columns appear to be aligned, then you can specify a suitable length for the string with the `%c` conversion specifier.

```
while (fscanf("%d %45c %lf", &intarr[size], &string[size], &dblarr[size]) == 3)
    size++;
```

Note that two of your three array names are impossible in C (or C++); the types `int` and `double` are reserved words and cannot be used as variable names. The exact length of the string is determined by the file format; I counted it as 45, but choose your value to suit (a comment mentions 34 characters, which happens to be the length of "Queensville Side Road, Queensville"). The scanned name will include trailing blanks in general; you can arrange to remove them if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us anything about the address field in the middle. I am just assuming it does not contain digits or `-` or `+` and I am not assuming the second number starts at some fixed column (e.g. because the input might have tab characters, so visually the second numbers could be aligned, but their relative offset -to start of line- might not be fixed).

I would read the file line by line, and process each line:

```
 char* line=NULL;
 size_t linesize= 0;
 while (!feof (fil)) {
    ssize_t linelen = getline(&line, &linesize);
    if (linelen<0) break;
    // read the first number
    char* pc = NULL;
    long firstnum = strtol (line, &pc, 0);
    if (!pc || pc == line) break;
    // skip to start of second number
    while (*pc && !isdigit(*pc) && *pc != '-' && *pc != '+') pc++;
    char* startsec = pc;
    double secondnum = strtod(startsec, &pc);
    if (!pc || pc == startsec) break;
    do_something_with_numbers (firstnum, secondnum); 
 }
 free (line);
 fclose (fil);
```

If you could tell us more about the address field, we could help more!

Comment: The string in the middle only has one , or none at all. The rest are all characters. Im looking for the shortest and simplest way