# fscanf to read hour format

Tags: c, file-io

Is there a way to read a HH:MM format from a file using `fscanf()`, and treat it like an int? The file has this format :

```
3 14:50 20.10
```

Is it possible to do something like `fscanf(fp, "%d ... %f, &a, &b, &c);` and `b` will have 1450?

Comment: Have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450333/fscanf-with-colon-delimited-data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do this in a line. However, you can:

```
fscanf(fp, "%d %d:%d %f", &a, &b1, &b2, &c);
b = b1 * 100 + ((b1 > 0) * 2 - 1) * b2; // in case b1, b2 are the different sign.
```

Comment: Works fine as long as `b1`, `b2` are the same sign.  Consider `-14:50`.

Comment: @chux But an "hour format" doesn't contain negative numbers

Comment: Though less common, "hours formats" are used to express negative times too, especial timezone offsets.  [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newfoundland_Time_Zone).  Direct application of this answer can lead to an incorrect result.

Comment: @chux Answer improved